# Compute great circle tracks on a sphere in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, matlab

I would like to know if there is a equivalent function in python 2.7 that the track2 function in matlab [1](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/track2.html?requestedDomain=de.mathworks.com). This function is used for Geographic tracks from starting and ending points.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Haven't you got your answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

There is a toolbox. **geopy** toolbox which I guess is what you want.

[**geopy**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy)

**Example:**
Measuring Distance

Geopy can calculate geodesic distance between two points using the Vincenty distance or great-circle distance formulas, with a default of Vincenty available as the class geopy.distance.distance, and the computed distance available as attributes (e.g., miles, meters, etc.).

Here’s an example usage of Vincenty distance:

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty
newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)
print(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
538.3904451566326
```

Using great-circle distance:

```
from geopy.distance import great_circle
newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)
print(great_circle(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
537.1485284062816
```

Answer (score 0):

My python package
[GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python) can
compute waypoints along a geodesic on an ellipsoid.  If the flattening
of the ellipsoid is set to zero, the geodesics become great circles.
Sample code is given
[here](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python/examples.html#computing-waypoints).